Writing dental notations
I am trying to include dental notations in a document.
I would like the notations to look like this.

This is what I could do so far.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello$\lceil 5$ ~~~~~~~hello $5 \rceil$ ~~~~~hello $\lfloor 5$ ~~~~~~~~~hello $5 \rfloor$\\[.2cm]

hello\begin{tabular}{|c}
\hline
5\\
\end{tabular}
~~~hello
\begin{tabular}{c|}
\hline
5\\
\end{tabular}
~~~hello
\begin{tabular}{|c}
5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
~~~hello
\begin{tabular}{c|}
5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


So you want Palmer notation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmer_notation (Direction for solution included ...)

Something like this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tooth}{mm}
 {% #1 = ll or lr or ul or ur, #2 = number
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \arraystretch { 0 }
  \dim_set:Nn \tabcolsep { 0pt }
  \raisebox
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_head:n { #1 } } {u} { \dim_eval:n { \depth-1pt} } { 0pt }
   }
   {
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_head:n { #1 } } {u} { \hline }
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_tail:n { #1 } } {l} { \vline \, #2 \,}
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_tail:n { #1 } } {r} { \, #2 \, \vline }
    \vrule width 0pt height \dim_eval:n { \fontcharht\font`0 + 1pt } depth 1pt
    \\
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_head:n { #1 } } {l} { \hline }
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X \tooth{ll}{5} \tooth{lr}{5} \tooth{ul}{5} \tooth{ur}{5} X

\end{document}


Here's a version where, if the second argument is empty, the frame is drawn with thicker lines.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tooth}{mm}
 {% #1 = ll or lr or ul or ur, #2 = number
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \arraystretch { 0 }
  \dim_set:Nn \tabcolsep { 0pt }
  \tl_if_blank:nT {#2} { \dim_set:Nn \arrayrulewidth { 0.6pt } }
  \raisebox
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_head:n { #1 } } {u} { \dim_eval:n { \depth-1pt} } { 0pt }
   }
   {
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_head:n { #1 } } {u} { \hline }
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_tail:n { #1 } } {l}
      { \vline \, \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2} {\phantom{0}\kern-0.2pt } {#2}  \,}
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_tail:n { #1 } } {r}
      { \, \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2} {\phantom{0}\kern-0.2pt } {#2} \, \vline }
    \vrule width 0pt height \dim_eval:n { \fontcharht\font`0 + 1pt } depth 1pt
    \\
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_head:n { #1 } } {l} { \hline }
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X \tooth{ll}{5} \tooth{lr}{5} \tooth{ul}{5} \tooth{ur}{5} X

X \tooth{ll}{} \tooth{lr}{} \tooth{ul}{} \tooth{ur}{} X

\end{document}


If you change the thickness in case of the empty argument, remember also to compensate with the \kern-0.2pt: the amount should be the difference between the default 0.4pt and the thicker width.

Thank you very much for your time, and very nice code.

Just one enquiry. Is it possible to control the thickness of the horizontal and vertical lines. Thank you

@Hany You're welcome! See edit.

Thank you very much for your concern.

The last thing to ask. Could the line width be changed for a specific application without specifying the tooth as in  {\tooth{ul}{5}}

@Hany I'm not sure I understand the request.

I would like to use an empty quadrant in an explanatory text position, and I want the lines of this specific location to be thicker than the others, to be more obvious.

@Hany Now I guess I understood, see edit.

Thank you very very much. I appreciate your concern and effort very much. I added the line: \dim_set:Nn \arrayrulewidth { 1pt } to increase the default arrayrulewidth, and made the empty arrayrulewidth 2pt. This made me control both conditions as needed.

@greg Please refer to my posted answer, for my modifications, and their reasons.

As there are unicode defined codepoints for the Palmer notation I elected to rather use unicode. I use the symbola font (noto symbols might also have them). Also did a bit of  background reading to understand the domain (thanks @MS-PRO for the wiki link).  The Palmer notation consists of a symbol (⏌⎿ ⏋⎾) designating in which quadrant the tooth is found and a number indicating the position from the midline. As to why uniicode a) the text will be copyable  b) screen readers might have a better chance to read it aloud correctly and c) it is not maths, so semantically it is more correct. Please compile with LuaTeX or XeLaTeX.As an aside these symbols are very similar to what Napier used for roots.

  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontface\symbola{symbola}
    \begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new:Npn \l_palmer_ul:n #1
     { ~\symbola ⏌#1~}
    \cs_new:Npn \l_palmer_ur:n #1
     { ~\symbola⎿ #1~}
    \cs_new:Npn \l_palmer_lr:n #1
     { ~\symbola  #1⏋~}
    \cs_new:Npn \l_palmer_ll:n #1
     { ~\symbola #1⏋~}
    
    \NewDocumentCommand\tooth{mm}
    {{  
        \use:c{l_palmer_#1:n} {#2}
    }}
    
    \NewDocumentCommand\DentalChart{}
    {
      \int_step_inline:nnnn{8}{-1}{1}
        {\l_palmer_ur:n {##1}}
      \int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{8}
        {\l_palmer_ul:n {##1}}  
       \par 
       \bigskip
       \int_step_inline:nnnn{8}{-1}{1}
        {\l_palmer_lr:n {##1}}
      \int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{8}
        {\l_palmer_ll:n {##1}}    
    }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    
    \DentalChart
    
    \bigskip\bigskip
    
    \tooth{ur}{5} Extract immediately!
    
    \end{document}


Nice solution, nice coding

@MS-SPO  Thanks means a lot to me coming from you.

@yannisl Thank you

I am very grateful to egreg for the very nice code. Please refer to the answer and its edit, for the original code.
I have one observation to mention.
When the code was written, it was designed from the coding point of view. So, when the original code says
\tooth{ll}

it defines the left and lower lines, when actually the designated tooth is the upper left tooth.
To apply the code from the Dentist point of view, I redefined the upper, lower, right and left designations of the code.
So when the code mentions
\tooth{ll}{5}

it displays the lower left second premolar, as it should.
I have requested egreg to make the lines thicker when mentioning the quadrant designation without actually designating a tooth inside it.
So, I have, also, defined the default arrayrulewidth, to control it as desired.
So, the outcome of the rewritten code, is:

My modified code, to be used by dentists is as follows
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tooth}{mm}
 {% #1 = ll or lr or ul or ur, #2 = number
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \arraystretch { 0 }%the length of the vertical line
  \dim_set:Nn \arrayrulewidth { .8pt }%this line was not in the original code. It is added by me to control the default line thickness. In the original code, where this line was not present, the default line thickness was .4pt 
  \dim_set:Nn \tabcolsep { 0pt }%the length of the horizontal line
  \tl_if_blank:nT {#2} { \dim_set:Nn \arrayrulewidth { 1.6pt } }%the line thickness, if the second argument (for the tooth number) is empty
  \raisebox
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_head:n { #1 } } {l} { \dim_eval:n { \depth-1pt} } { 0pt }
   }
   {
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_head:n { #1 } } {l} { \hline }
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_tail:n { #1 } } {r}
      { \, \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2} {\phantom{0}\kern-0.2pt } {#2} \, \vline }
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_tail:n { #1 } } {l}
      { \vline \, \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2} {\phantom{0}\kern-0.2pt } {#2} \, }
    \vrule width 0pt height \dim_eval:n { \fontcharht\font`0 + 1pt } depth 1pt%The first 1pt is for the length of the vrule above the tooth number. The second 1pt (depth) is for the length of the vrule below the tooth number.
    \\
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_head:n { #1 } } {u} { \hline }
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \group_end:
}
%If you change the thickness in case of the empty argument, remember also to compensate with the \kern-0.2pt: the amount should be the difference between the default 0.4pt and the thicker width.
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
ur ~\tooth{ur}{5} ~~~~ ul ~\tooth{ul}{5} ~~~~ lr ~\tooth{lr}{5} ~~~~  ll ~\tooth{ll}{5}\\

ur ~\tooth{ur}{} ~~~~ ul ~\tooth{ul}{} ~~~~ lr ~\tooth{lr}{} ~~~~  ll ~\tooth{ll}{}
\end{document}

